# Objective-c singleton creation

Tags: objective-c

Code sample 1:

```
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance{
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

code sample 2

```
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance{
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Are there any differences in the result of the above code samples ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is better as it prevents multiple threads from creating multiple instances of the Singleton class given the necessary circumstances are met.

E.g: Take the 2nd example.

```
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance{
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Suppose `Theread1` executes the following LOC and then gives the handle to `Thread2`

```
if (!sharedInstance)
```

Now `Thread2` executes the following LOC and then hands over the handle to `Thread1`

```
sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

Now, since the if condition was met first by `Thread1`, `Thread1` will continue and execute the following LOC as well

```
sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

Now, you have 2 instances of `MyClass` created.

Therefore, the 1st approach is best. It will make sure the block within

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    });
```

gets executed only Once!

However, if you ONLY access the Singleton via the Main Thread (UI thread), then the second scenario will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dispatch_once()` is faster and it performs something only once so if you access it twice from different threads there won't be any problems.

Comment: How's `dispatch_once` faster than `if`? it's faster then `@synchronized`, yes, but the second code sample doesn't have `@synchronized`.